# How do I deploy two Laravel 7 project into shared hosting at hostGator?

Tags: laravel, deploying, public-html

I tried many strategies to deploy two Laravel apps in shared hosting. What I have done so far is

- created a folder inside public_html folder (vocalpublic) and put all the Laravel public folder files in there.
- All the other Laravel project files except public folder have placed outside the public_html folder (example.co.uk)
- I have many addon domains, and in this case, I created one (example.co.uk) which was created a folder outside the public_hml folder, and that's where I drop laravel files.

Final result:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the viewers.

I found the solution. The PHP version of my server is 7.1 max but my Laravel 7.2 need at least PHP 7.2 version. So what I did was downgrade the Laravel app into version 5.8, and everything works fine.

Thanks.